Novel where a time traveler visits Great Library of Alexandria
The main character purchases ticket at time traveling agency to go back in time to when Great Library of Alexandria still existed. Once there he visits the Library, but he noticed many anachronistic elements everywhere he goes, including the content of the books. When he returns to his own time, the official at agency explains that he experienced subjective past that resembles only what modern people believe it's supposed to look like and there is no way to travel to objective past.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Do you remember the cover art?

Valorum was right in their answer below. That story was "The Bird of Time" by George Alec Effinger. :)

Jacob, please accept Valorum's answer by clicking on the checkmark under the voting arrows in the upper-left corner of the answer.  It will give you a bit of bonus reputation but, more importantly, future searches will show the question as having been correctly answered.

Roger. It's done. :)

This is The Bird of Time by George Alec Effinger.

Far into the future, Hartstein's graduation present from his grandparents was a wonderful trip…into the past. He had a long future in the doughnut industry to look forward to but this trip was the icing on the cake. It had been a long time since that first experiment in time travel was successfully pulled off, although not without its flaws. Now, in the future, time travel was a lucrative tourist industry. But the time travel industry was keeping one little fact to itself: two percent never came back. This cover-up was the work of the Agency. The Agency knew what others did not: that the past wasn't really the past but a complicated dynamic of individual perceptions of what the past might have been. The past isn't real and reality becomes a state of mind. While selling their particular brand of escapist entertainment and vacation packages, the Agency didn't bother to tell its clients or the populace in general that a war was going on--a time war. The Agency was spending its time in a neck-and-neck battle with the Temporary Underground. The battlefield was none other than the space-time continuum, the weapons were time-shifts and theoretical mathematics. Hartstein had no idea what his trip would be or where it would take him.


Hartstein is unimpressed with concept, repeatedly describing time travel as basically being a scam.

“Uh huh. What do you mean, no such thing as the past? Where am I
going, then?”
“No objective past, I said. There’s definitely a past, all right.
You’re going to Alexandria and you’re going to see the Library. While
you’re in town, by the way, why don’t you run up to Pharos and see the
lighthouse? It was one of the Seven Wonders of the Ancient World, you
know, and it was still standing where you’re going. But tell me, you
think that time travel is more exciting than, oh, spending a few days
in Las Vegas?”


Yes! That's exactly the story I was thinking of. Although, it seems I only read its first chapter those many years ago. I think I read that Alexandria fragment in some science-fiction/fantasy magazine. Thank you for the help! :)
